# Set multiple input values as properties of a useState object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form asking for different inputs from the user. I want to store the user inputs in a `useState` object.

How can I do that in an optimized way? That is, without making different `handleChange` functions for each input.

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
```

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter password" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `name` attribute in the input tags to specify the different inputs.

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="username" ... />
    <input type="text" name="email" ... />
    <input type="text" name="password" ... />
  </form>
```

Then, get the name and value of the event from `e.target` to generalise the changes.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target; // <--

  setUser((prevUser) => ({
    ...prevUser,
    [name]: value,
  }));

  console.log(user);
};
```